# Probability of quantum transition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, probability, measurement-problem, born-rule

I have a question about a task:

> We have a particle, which is in a linear combination of the first two states of the harmonic oscillator, which we can parametrise as  $|\psi\rangle=\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})\space |0\rangle +e^{i\phi}\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})|1\rangle$, where $0\leq\theta \leq \pi $ and $\leq \phi<2\pi$,  what is the probability of finding the particle in the state of $|a\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)$.

I know that the right answer is the projection of $|a\rangle$ onto $|\psi\rangle$ squared, so $P=|\langle \psi,a\rangle|^2 $, but why is that so ? I understand that we need to project $|\psi\rangle$ onto a eigenvector ($|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$), if we want to find the probability of measuring/finding the particle in a eigenstate.

What about finding the particle in a non eigenstate, what is the interpretation of this, since we can only measure eigenstates?

Comment: Why is that so? - It is called the Born rule, and it is a postulate of QM.  What is the interpretation of finding the particle in a non eigenstate? - How do you expect to do this given that, as you've said yourself, we can only measure eigenstates of operators?

Comment: "The transition probability $P(\psi,\theta)$ from a state $\psi$ to a state $\theta$, or, in other words the probability of a "quantum jump" from $\psi$ to $\theta$ is  $P(\psi,\theta)=|\langle \psi,\theta\rangle|^2$ " This is what I have found in one of the pdfs, and I think this is what I am looking for. I just dont understand why that is so, why would a projection like that give a probability...

Comment: I am terribly sorry I have misread, I have now edited the question . Sorry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specific case you mention, the particle either is in the state you are looking for or not, so that you have to set $\theta$ and $\phi$ so that they fit the state sought. You want $cos(\theta)=sin(\theta)$ and $e^{i\phi}=0$ so $\theta=\pi/4$ and $\phi=0$.

Yet in general a state can evolve over time and you may wonder "when will it reach a given state $|\chi\rangle$ during its evolution".

You then impose $ \langle \chi |\psi\rangle=1$ which is not a jump probability (the state is not jumping, it's evolving) but rather a projection (it is one when the states are the same).

In your case, even if it is not evolving, you have to project. You then get:
$${1\over \sqrt{2}}(\langle 0 | +\langle 1 |)|(\cos(\theta) |0 \rangle+\sin(\theta)e^{i\phi}|1\rangle)=1$$

You are then imposing that the states are the same one by imposing that their scalar product is unitary (assuming everything is normalised).

Then:
$${1\over \sqrt{2}}\cos(\theta)+{1\over \sqrt{2}}\sin(\theta)e^{i\phi}=1$$
Which you can solve, but it is solved by the condition mentioned above:
$\cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$ and $e^{i\phi}=0$ so $\theta=\pi/4$ and $\phi=0$.

(The complex part is zero only if $\phi=0$ or $\theta=0$. If $\theta=0$ you would get for the real part $\cos(0)=\sqrt{2}$ so it has to be $\phi=0$. And then $\theta=\pi/4$. Plus periodicity, of course.)

In general though, the probability that a state $|\psi\rangle$ when measured gives you a given result $|\chi\rangle$ is $ \langle \chi|\psi\rangle^2$ as you mentioned. Think of it has: "I am using a magical operator which has $|\chi\rangle$ as eigenvector. Then of course is such operator does not exist you will never measure it, yet $ \langle \chi |\psi\rangle$ still gives you an indication about the "amount" of  $|\chi\rangle$ inside $|\psi\rangle$ (or rather, their superposition in vector space).
In your case:

$${1\over \sqrt{2}}\cos(\theta)+{1\over \sqrt{2}}\sin(\theta)e^{i\phi}$$
gives you, as $\theta$ and $\phi$ vary, of how similar your state is to ${1\over 2}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)$.

Comment: But the projection depends on $\theta$ and $\phi$, so for a given $\theta$ and $\phi$ I will get a state, and a value of the projection/probability of measruing the state $|a\rangle$, but if my system is now in a certain state, shouldn't I allways measure that state, that the system is in, not the state $|a\rangle$ ?? $|a\rangle$ actually  means measuring the $|1\rangle$ or $|0\rangle$ with the same probabilty = 1/2 .

Comment: That is what I was trying to say: you are mixing up two things:
1-if the system is in state *a*  and you measure it with an operator *O* you can only get its eigenvectors as new states. 
2-in your case, your state is fixed (depending on the values of $\theta$ and $\phi$). Thus it will never be in another state, *unless* $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the right one. The projection only tells you how close you are to the state you are looking for *or* you can impose perfect projection (1) to find the right values of the parameters.

If the state is given you can only measure an operator eigenstates

Comment: Given *a* you can measure 1 or 2 using the harmonic hamiltonian.
You may measure other stuff with another operator which does not commute with the Hamiltonian.
If you devised an operator capable of measuring 1+2 (meaning its eigenstates include 1+2) you could try to measure it, but will not measure it *unless* the projection is different from 0. 
If it is one you will measure it with certainty, otherwise it depends on the sqared projection.

Comment: Oh... I see what you did with the magical operator, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You measure eigenstates of the operator you use to measure. In general a state may live as a superposition of states (eigenstates) of another operator.

Comment: I am terribly sorry I have misread, I have now edited the question . Sorry !